# Dynamically adjust positioning of an HTML element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding

I have a script that will increase and decrease the size of a period. The end result is to have a period that will increase and decrease in size while remaining stationary.

The current problem I am having is when the size is increased (or decreased), the element will move down and up the page (respectively).

To counter this, I have attempted to adjust the padding as the font size is increased. This adjustment doesn't work, and the element continues to move.

Here is my Javascript:

```
window.dotFluxOut = true;
var i = 1;
var pad = 50;

var dots = window.setInterval(function () {
    var wait = document.getElementById("wait");

    if (window.dotFluxOut) {
        wait.style.fontSize = i + "px";
        wait.style.padding = (pad - i) + "px";
        i++;
    } else {
        wait.style.fontSize = i + "px";
        wait.style.padding = (pad - i) + "px";
        i--;
    }

    if (parseInt(wait.style.fontSize.replace("px", "")) > 180) {
        window.dotFluxOut = false;
    } else if (parseInt(wait.style.fontSize.replace("px", "")) < 3) {
        window.dotFluxOut = true;
    }

}, 5);
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<p id="wait" align="center" style="font-size: 160px">.</p>
```

**EDIT:**

If you would like to see it running: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayumz/Yu3wv/)

Comment: i've had some luck, with absolute positioning, setting line-height to 0; and adjusting top, left to counter the movement. Not posting because it's not precise or pretty, but rather a hack. Hopefully someone can come up with a better solution. I've tried the suggestions , it seems line height still gets increased in webkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the line-height is automatically changing with with font-size as is the margin associated with the

tag.

If you initially set to line height to be the slightly bigger than the maximum font size this should help resolve the issue.

e.g.

```
<p id="wait" align="center" style="font-size: 160px; line-height:200px; margin:0">.</p>
```

The second problem is that the white space above and below the period/full-stop character grows with the change in font-size i.e. to allow for the tall characters (bdfhijklt) and the characters with tails (gjpqy).

The best I have come up with is:

```
<p align="center" style="margin:0"><span id="wait" style="font-size:160px">.</span><span style="font-size:200px">&nbsp;</span></p>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've attempted this solution, but the problem persists. Could the style that is being applied in the 'if' statements overwrite this default value?

Comment: Updated answer above, it's not perfect but should get you a little closer.

Comment: Thanks! That worked straight away! I forgot I could have used &nbsp!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the line-height of the dot-container equal to its height.